# query synchronisation mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to web programming and I'm making a site and I need to know this thing:
I have a database with a counter and a php page that updates it.
es

```
//in pseudo code
n = get_counter_from_db(); //calls select*from table....
n+=1;
//do something with n without modifing it
update_counter_in();//calls update table set counter=n....
```

my question is:
if two pcs run at the same time this page is it possible that the counter will be update just by one because it happends the next thing?

```
//counter = 0
pc1 gets the counter, n = 0 and adds 1 n = 1
pc2 gets the counter, n= 0 and adds 1 n = 1
pc1 updates the counter, counter = 1
pc2 updates the counter, counter = 1
```

Or are the two pages processed by the server one after the other? or won't mySQL let this happen? How? And, for learning pourposes, how will the two queries  work?
(Sorry for the bad english)

Comment: Combine both queries into one: `update table set field = 1+field`. Not sure if this will solve the problem, but it will make at least the code simpler.

Comment: I need to know che counter. Is it possible to pass two queries at the same time(SELECT + UPDATE)?

Answer (score 0):

Better use increment in your update_counter_in:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `yourfield` = `yourfield` + $incValue WHERE ...;
```

instead of

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `yourfield` = $newValue WHERE ...;
```

This will prevent race-condition from your example.

Comment: I need to know che counter. Is it possible to pass two queries at the same time(SELECT + UPDATE)?

Comment: You can first make increment of field, and then select it's new value.

Comment: yes, but if pc1 adds 1, then pc2 adds 1 then pc1 asks for counter it will have a wrong value

Comment: Why? Lets suggest that we had N visitors. Pc1 adds, then pc2 adds, then pc1 asks for counter, and it will return N+2 - which is correct - because at the moment when pc1 asks for counter we already had N+2 visitors. Then pc2 asks for value, and it will return N+2, which is also correct.

Comment: but it's not what i need, i need the counter to use it like an id, so pc1 need to have id=1 and pc2 id=2

Comment: You want to give each user unique id? Make table like CREATE TABLE visitors (`id` AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, .....some another fields you need.....), and just make insert without setting id: INSERT INTO `visitors` SET anotherfield1=..., anotherfield2=..., then use http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php to get last id.

Comment: no, it's not what i need. the question is if i can simply do what i have said. i'm reading about transaction. is it the right way?